# Sonatype Nexus remote repo but eclipse never gets missing jars

Tags: maven, repository, pom.xml, nexus, sonatype

I installed and set up nexus yesterday allowing anonymous access as I can view the repo from my browser Ok without any login, this was on a red hat server.

I then removed some of my own jar files from my local maven repo and addded the following to the top of my pom file:

```
<repositories>
  <repository>     
    <id>projectX</id>
    <name>projectX</name>
    <url>http://testapp:8081/nexus/content/repositories/projectX/</url>
  </repository>
```

When I now right click my project in eclipse and the choose maven >> update project it never seems to go to the repository on my testapp and get the missing jar files, instead I just have project reference problems and problems in the pom file.

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong? The URL for the repo in nexus as indicated via the web browser is correct and I can copy this from my pom file into my browser and hit it ok.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Can you also try adding the following to the `<repository>` section - assuming you are using the same repo for release versions?

```
<repository>
  <releases>
    <enabled>true</enabled>
    <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
    <checksumPolicy>warn</checksumPolicy>
  </releases>
  <snapshots>
    <enabled>false</enabled>
    <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
    <checksumPolicy>fail</checksumPolicy>
  </snapshots>
  ...
</repository>
```

You may need to do the same for `<pluginRepositories>` as well, assuming these are served off your nexus.

Instead of updating `pom.xml`, you could declare these within a `profile` in your `settings.xml` so that you can re-use this across projects.

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply, this didnt seem to make a difference but it seems like some files can be retrieved from the repository whilst others (which are there) cannot. I get this warning in the log file (eclipse maven console) for a particular jar which doesnt work: 18/03/2014 12:53:27 GMT: [WARN] The POM for com.intersys:CacheDB:jar:4.2.1224.0 is missing, no dependency information available - oddly the jar file is there and so is a pom file.

Comment: @pao You may want to relook at the pom file, if present.  Maybe it is in the wrong place.  Maybe the version is different from the jar.  Did nexus generate it for you or did you upload it manually?

Comment: Hi thanks again, I kind of cheated I suppose, I took the local .m2 directory from my windows machine and then copied it over to the linux server as I had a lot of custom jar files that were only in my local repo. I think this might have had something to do with it, but what I am not sure as I am quite new to using maven as we have only just started to adopt this approach.

Comment: I deleted the CacheDB jar file completely from the remote repo and then used maven on the server to install the file into the repo, eclipse still cannot grab the file from the remote repo, same error..

Comment: The pom file looks ok.

Comment: @pom How about uploading that specific jar manually to nexus through web interface, allowing nexus to generate the pom if it does not exist?

Comment: I will try this as what I actually did was to use maven from the commandline to load the file into the repository. So... when using nexus is it recommended to only use the nexus interface to load in jars as opposed to using maven from the commandline via script and then hoping nexus will manage the repository properly?